# Object detection torchvision : IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I'm working on clothes detection in an image. For this, i'm using the package TorchVision on python, and i want to start from a pretrained model and to fintetune it for my classes (different kind of clothes). My images are in a zip file. When i run the function train_one_epoch, i obtain this error :

> ```
> IOError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 99, in _worker_loop
>     samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
>   File "<ipython-input-16-4557e2f6ca8b>", line 51, in __getitem__
>     img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2530, in open
>     fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
> IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train.zip/062fc2042f49d10fa625151cb652c3da.jpg'
> ```

Here is a part of my code :

```
python

num_classes = 46 + 1
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

dataset_train = FashionDataset('gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train.zip/', # "../input/imaterialist-fashion-2019-FGVC6/train/",
                               'gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train.csv.zip', #"../input/imaterialist-fashion-2019-FGVC6/train.csv",
                               256,
                               256,
                               transforms=get_transform(train=True))


model_ft = get_instance_segmentation_model(num_classes)
model_ft.to(device)

data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset_train, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=8,
    collate_fn=lambda x: tuple(zip(*x)))

params = [p for p in model_ft.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=0.001,
                            momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0005)

lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,
                                               step_size=5,
                                               gamma=0.1)
num_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    train_one_epoch(model_ft, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
    lr_scheduler.step()

torch.save(model_ft.state_dict(), "model.bin")
```

Comment: What is FashionDataset? where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting above error because `train.zip` is a zip file, not a folder. So, first unzip `train.zip` file using below code:

```
import zipfile
zr1 = zipfile.ZipFile("/content/gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train.zip", 'r')
zr1.extractall("/content/gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train/")
zr1.close()
```

And, then change `'gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train.zip/'` to `'gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train/'`

Also, `train.csv.zip` is a zip file, extract it first before actually using it. Use below code:

```
zr2 = zipfile.ZipFile("/content/gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train.csv.zip", 'r')
zr2.extractall("/content/gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/")
zr2.close()
```

And, then change `'gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train.csv.zip'` to something like `'gdrive/My Drive/donnees_kaggle_iMaterialist/train.csv.csv'`.

Note one thing here that extracted `csv` file name would be `train.csv.csv`(with extension) as zipfile name was `train.csv.zip`.

Comment: I've just finally solved the problem, and you're right, i have unziped the folder and it worked. Thanks for your answer !!